# can the cascade-correlation neural network be implemented in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

Is the [cascade-correlation](http://www.neuralware.com/images/cascade-correlation-fahlman.pdf) neural network implementable in tensorflow?

The cascade-correlation algorithm not only determines the weights of the neural network but also its architecture

Comment: good question, but honestely I do not why the TF's team did not implement it...